# Why does this work in a for loop but not forEach? (array is not a constructor error)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Right now I am trying to create an array of objects that have numbers greater than `0`, and when the number is `0` the array ends , when the number is greater than `0` a new array should be created (therefore the function should return an array of arrays, broken up when there are 0's in the middle.

Input and desired output:

```
input = [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,9,9,0,0]
output = [[1,2,3,4][9,9]]
```

My function (so far):

```
function group(Array) {
  let allArray = []
  let runGroup = new Array()
  Array.forEach(function(runtimeI,index) {
    if (runtimeI > 0)
   { 
      runGroup[i] = new Array()
      runGroup[i].push(runtimeI)
    }


    }
  )
  allArray.push(runGroup[i])

}
 array = [10,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,15,0,0,0,5,5,5,]

console.log(group(array))
```

The function I created throws an error saying `array is not a constructor`

working example function (that creates the kind of structure I need)

```
var squares = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{
    squares[i] = new Array();
    for(var j = (i * 20) + 1; j <= 20 * i + 20; j++)
        if (squares[i] == null)
            squares[i] = j;
        else
            squares[i].push(j);
}

console.log(squares)
```

so I guess my question is, is there something about for loops that forEach can't do? is there another way I should be accomplishing this?

Comment: The `.forEach()` code you posted has several errors; have you checked the console?

Comment: `Array.forEach`? you're just calling a forEach on...nothing in particular. What should this iterate over?

Comment: It's written as a function the top line just disappeared because I accidentally formatted it on the same line as the ``` marks. I've now made edits to fix it.

Comment: `group(Array)` *that's worse*! `new Array()` now does NOT make a new array but calls `new` on the input.

Comment: woha, how do I fix that? I can see kind of what you're saying now, my problem is I need to iterate over the array that is the argument, then create a multidimensional array as a result (which would be a new array for each group of numbers over 0 inside of the bigger array) 

What you're saying though is so far I'm actually overwriting the original argument by using this variable ...

Comment: Don't shadow the `Array` constructor function for a start. It can also help to use the array literal initialiser - `[]` instead of `new Array` but shadowing `Array` is still confusing.

Comment: `function group(Array) {` — Don't mask global functions with local variables that have the same name. Don't use variables that start with a capital letter for things that are not constructor functions.

Comment: WOW that makes complete sense , I thought by naming it Array I could give it any Array as long as the object type is ARRAY , but maybe i could name it literally anything else and avoid this problem ?

Comment: The name of the parameter doesn't determine its type in any way. It's just what you call that parameter. You could call it `foo` or `x` and there would be no change to behaviour as long as your code consistently refers to the same name. The name *can* shadow an existing construct in JS, as you've seen - there is no way to differentiate `Array` the custom variable from `Array` the global array constructor function. You can also shadow other things like `undefined` if you choose them as a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with smallish arrays, a combination of joining and splitting is a concise way to filter out the 0's...

```js
let input = [1,27,3,4,0,0,0,9,9,0,0];
let arrays = input.join('&').split('&0');
let output = arrays.filter(a => a).map(s => s.split('&').filter(s => s).map(s => parseInt(s)))
console.log(output);
```

In English: Join produces a string of all of the input digits.  Splitting on '0' produces an array of arrays, empty at the delimiter ('0').  Remove the empty ones and split them again to produce arrays of digits.

Alternatively, probably more appropriate for large arrays, using a more iterative style, as your OP began...

```js
let input = [1, 27, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 0, 0];
let output = [];
let runGroup = [];

input.forEach(num => {
  if (num === 0) {
    if (runGroup.length) {
      output.push(runGroup);
      runGroup = [];
    }
  } else {
    runGroup.push(num);
  }
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: what if numbers are greater than 9?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - agreed.  added a non-numeric delimiter.

Comment: I would probably be looking at arrays with thousands of values , but I will check into solutions with that in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @JasonHarder - edited to approach iteratively for larger arrays.

Comment: Thanks @danh !! great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could abuse the split/join method as follow

```
// Build a string from your initial array
var step1 = input.join('#')
// Remove the '0' and build arrays around it
var step2 = step1.split('#0')
// Filter empty values
var step3 = step2.filter(v => v)
// Build the final result
var output = step3.map(v => v.split('#').filter(s => s))
```

[image]

Comment: what if numbers are greater than 9?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one problem in your code - inside `Array.forEach` you use index `i` instead of `index`. As alternative you can use following code

```js
input = [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,9,9,0,0]

output = input.join().replace(/(,0)+/g,'-').replace(/-$/,'')
              .split('-,').map(x=>x.split(',').map(y=>+y))

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```